# Javascript Regular expression capture

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm sure there might be something simular on stack overflow but I can't find anything and am getting quite frustrated with what should be very simple.

I need to capture part of a url (similar to a url rewriting engine) using javascript.

**URL structure:**

```
http://example.com/constant/CAPTURETHIS

http://example.com/constant/CAPTURETHIS/

http://example.com/constant/CAPTURETHIS#noise

http://example.com/constant/CAPTURETHIS/#noise
```

I need to just return the CAPTURETHIS text for all 3 senerios

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JavaScript supports the retrieval of regex capture-groups by using [a string object's `match` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) or [a regular-expression object's `exec` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec):

```
var captureThis = url.match(/^http:[/][/]example[.]com[/]constant[/]([^/]+)/)[1];
var captureThis = /^http:[/][/]example[.]com[/]constant[/]([^/]+)/.exec(url)[1];
```

But for your example, I almost wonder if it's simpler to use [the string object's `split` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split):

```
var captureThis = url.split(/[/]/)[4];
```

Comment: +1 for mentioning `split()` if nothing else. People seem to forget that "not using regex" is often the easier option when you're not validating a whole string